# create pdf file of page with dynamic content

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I need to create a PDF file of a php page that includes php variables and js generated content.

I tried achieving this with mPDF and the following script:

```
require_once "libraries/mpdf/mpdf.php";

ob_start();  // start output buffering
include 'appartamento.php';
$content = ob_get_clean(); // get content of the buffer and clean the buffer
$mpdf = new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output(); // output as inline content
```

However, the generated pdf does only include very few content of the php page and i don't know what needs to be done to display the whole content in the pdf file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To generate the dynamic content, treat your `$content` variable is any PHP variable and set it initially.

After that, where you are populating the content in your loop, ensure to use the below logic.

```
$content = $content . "Your additional Content";
```

In this way, you will append to your variable.

Finally, use the below code to generate the PDF.

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);

$mpdf->Output();

exit;
```

You can easily use almost all the HTML tags in your `$content`. There are only some tags not supported.

That's it!

---

I have added the step-by-step process to ensure that you generate the PDF successfully with the dynamic data.

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',20,15,55,25,10,10); //This is where you set page size and margins. Feel free to use as is.

$mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;    // false is default.

$mpdf->SetProtection(array('print')); //You can find out about these details in mPDF guidelines.

$mpdf->AliasNbPages(['PAGETOTAL']); // PAGETOTAL gives you the value of Total Pages of your generated PDF.

$mpdf->SetTitle($your_title); //You can even set the PDF Title based on your Data.

$mpdf->SetAuthor($author_name); //You can set Author's Name as well

$mpdf->SetWatermarkText($watermark_text); //You can even set Watermark Text

$mpdf->showWatermarkText = false; //True if you want to show watermark

$mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed'; //Can even change Watermark Font

$mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.05; //Opacity of Watermark Text

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage'); //Obvious as mentioned

$content = $content . 'Your ' . $content . ' can be added this way.'; //This can be any HTML.

$mpdf->WriteHTML($content); //You can now compile your content and show in PDF.

$mpdf->Output(); //finally output it.
```

In addition to this, please note the following as well.

mPDF is divided into three main sections. These are to be in the `<body>` of your HTML.

1. `<htmlpageheader name="myheader">` - This is repeated on every page as a header. Can be your logo from the page template. Will close `</htmlpageheader>`.

   2. `<htmlpagefooter name="myfooter">` - This will be similar to the header but at the bottom. Will close `</htmlpagefooter>`.
   3. This is your entire content in `<body>`.

To display the `<htmlpageheader name="myheader">` and `<htmlpagefooter name="myfooter">`, use the below lines of code.

```
<sethtmlpageheader name="myheader" value="on" show-this-page="1" />
<sethtmlpagefooter name="myfooter" value="on" />
```

Follow this logic and then try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

But it is still not working, maybe i still have the variables organised wrong. I keep trying, I'm kind of new to this topic.

Comment: What is the output that you are getting?

Comment: A lot of content of the page (images, icons, text) are not displayed at all and some or displayed incorrect. The thing is that the php page which I need to output as pdf contains a lot of php variables that come from a db and id's where the content comes from javascript functions.

Comment: Not an issue with mPDF. Before even trying with PDF, try your dynamic page as an HTML. if that shows correctly, it will be shown properly in the PDF as well. One more thing. Check your PDF's page size and margins.

Comment: I have further edited the code in order to explain it further. Do not hesitate in case you require further help.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org) library. It allows you to write a pdf from your PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the info i'll check this one out too.

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely check this out. A very helpful post by the way : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

And iff you are new to this, you might want to see how certain examples are rendered eventually : https://dompdf.net/examples.php